# How to get the bit depth of a CImg pixel?

Tags: c++, cimg

I'm trying to work out how many colour possibilities are used per pixel for any given image.

For example, if an image uses 8 bits per pixel, then it can represent one of 256 shades.

I'm looking for something like the following:

```
CImg<unsigned char> inputImage(inputImageFilename.c_str());
CImgDisplay disp_input(inputImage,"input");

std::cout << sizeof(inputImage[0]);
```

I know that this particular image has 8 bit pixel depth. I was hoping this would output 8, which I could then use as the exponent of 2 to get 256 (2^8 = 256). But it outputs 1, so this is not an option.

I've also tried `.depth()` but quickly realised this does not refer to the pixel depth.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Two things here:

1. The [documentation](http://cimg.eu/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#details) states:

   > Class representing an image (up to 4 dimensions wide), each pixel being of type T.

   which means the pixel depth is defined by the template type T. In your case this is `unsigned char` which results in a pixel depth of 8. If you want to have a pixel depth of 16 you could use `CImg<uint16_t>`.
2. Depending on the file type you are reading you can determine the bit depth. Jpeg for example has a bit depth of 8, while png can have a bit depth of 8 or 16 (at least that's whats supported by CImg). If you have a png file and want to know the bit depth you can use the function [load_png()](http://cimg.eu/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#aa2987878c3c335236ee64862e97a87b3) as follows:

   ```
    CImg<unsigned char> inputImage();
    unsigned int bit_depth;
    inputImage.load_png(inputImageFilename.c_str(), &bit_depth);
    std::cout << bit_depth;
   ```

   Since I used `unsigned char` as type T I will only have access to the first 8 bits even if the bit depth of the file is 16. Internally the image data is saved as unsigned short (aka 16 bit) if `bit_depth == 16`. So the following should be possible:

   ```
    if (bit_depth == 16)
        CImg<unsigned short> newImage(inputImage);
   ```

   The bit depth can of course also read from the exif data of the file.